# Extract part of a regex match

Tags: python, html, regex, html-content-extraction

I want a regular expression to extract the title from a HTML page. Currently I have this:

```
title = re.search('<title>.*</title>', html, re.IGNORECASE).group()
if title:
    title = title.replace('<title>', '').replace('</title>', '')
```

Is there a regular expression to extract just the contents of <title> so I don't have to remove the tags?

Comment: wow I can't believe all the responses calling to parse the entire HTML page just to extract a simple title. What overkill!

Comment: Question title says it all - the example given _happens_ to be HTML, but the general problem is ... general.

Answer (score 381, accepted):

Use `(` `)` in regexp and [`group(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.Match.group) in python to retrieve the captured string ([`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html#re.search) will return `None` if it doesn't find the result, so *don't use `group()` directly*):

```
title_search = re.search('<title>(.*)</title>', html, re.IGNORECASE)

if title_search:
    title = title_search.group(1)
```

Comment: If you're not doing anything when no title is found, why would it be a bad thing to use group() directly? (you can catch the exception anyway)

Comment: yeah, but most people forget about exceptions, and are really surprised when they see them at runtime :)

Comment: Don't forget to run `import re` or else you'll get `NameError: name 're' is not defined`

Answer (score 69):

Note that starting in `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), it's possible to improve a bit on [Krzysztof Krasoń's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1327389/9297144) by capturing the match result directly within the if condition as a variable and re-use it in the condition's body:

```py
# pattern = '<title>(.*)</title>'
# text = '<title>hello</title>'
if match := re.search(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE):
  title = match.group(1)
# hello
```

Comment: Oh, that's pretty.

Answer (score 12):

Try using capturing groups:

```
title = re.search('<title>(.*)</title>', html, re.IGNORECASE).group(1)
```

Answer (score 10):

May I recommend you to Beautiful Soup.  Soup is a very good lib to parse all of your html document.

```
soup = BeatifulSoup(html_doc)
titleName = soup.title.name
```

Comment: I would like to add, that beautifulsoup also parses incomplete html, and that's really nice.

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
title = re.search('<title>(.*)</title>', html, re.IGNORECASE).group(1)
```

Comment: If you really want to use REGEX for HTML parsing, don't run .group() directly on match, since it may return None.

Comment: You should use `.*?` so in case there are multiple `</title>` in the document (unlikely but you never knows).

Comment: @iElectric: you could put it in a try except block if you really want, right?

Answer (score 6):

```
re.search('<title>(.*)</title>', s, re.IGNORECASE).group(1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd think this should suffice:

```
#!python
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'<title>([^<]*)</title>', re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE)
pattern.search(text)
```

... assuming that your text (HTML) is in a variable named "text."

This also assumes that there are no other HTML tags which can be legally embedded inside of an HTML TITLE tag and there exists no way to legally embed any other < character within such a container/block.

**However** ...

Don't use regular expressions for HTML parsing in Python.  Use an HTML parser!  (Unless you're going to write a full parser, which would be a of extra, and redundant work when various HTML, SGML and XML parsers are already in the standard libraries).

If you're handling "real world" **tag soup** HTML (which is frequently non-conforming to any SGML/XML validator) then use the [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) package.  It isn't in the standard libraries (yet) but is widely recommended for this purpose.

Another option is: [lxml](http://lxml.de/) ... which is written for properly structured (standards conformant) HTML.  But it has an option to fallback to using BeautifulSoup as a parser: [ElementSoup](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html).

Comment: What is `re.MULTILINE` supposed to do here? It changes beginning-of-line `^` and end-of-line `$`, both of which you do not use.

Answer (score 4):

The provided pieces of code do not cope with `Exceptions`
May I suggest

```
getattr(re.search(r"<title>(.*)</title>", s, re.IGNORECASE), 'groups', lambda:[u""])()[0]
```

This returns an empty string by default if the pattern has not been found, or the first match.

Answer (score 3):

The currently top-voted answer by Krzysztof Krasoń fails with `<title>a</title><title>b</title>`. Also, it ignores title tags crossing line boundaries, e.g., for line-length reasons. Finally, it fails with `<title >a</title>` (which is valid HTML: [White space inside XML/HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314535/white-space-inside-xml-html-tags)).

I therefore propose the following improvement:

```
import re

def search_title(html):
    m = re.search(r"<title\s*>(.*?)</title\s*>", html, re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
    return m.group(1) if m else None
```

Test cases:

```
print(search_title("<title   >with spaces in tags</title >"))
print(search_title("<title\n>with newline in tags</title\n>"))
print(search_title("<title>first of two titles</title><title>second title</title>"))
print(search_title("<title>with newline\n in title</title\n>"))
```

Output:

```
with spaces in tags
with newline in tags
first of two titles
with newline
  in title
```

Ultimately, I go along with others recommending an HTML parser - not only, but also to handle non-standard use of HTML tags.

Answer (score 2):

I needed something to match `package-0.0.1` (name, version) but want to reject an invalid version such as `0.0.010`.

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iSKVEm/1) example.

```py
import re

RE_IDENTIFIER = re.compile(r'^([a-z]+)-((?:(?:0|[1-9](?:[0-9]+)?)\.){2}(?:0|[1-9](?:[0-9]+)?))$')

example = 'hello-0.0.1'

if match := RE_IDENTIFIER.search(example):
    name, version = match.groups()
    print(f'Name:     {name}')
    print(f'Version:  {version}')
else:
    raise ValueError(f'Invalid identifier {example}')
```

Output:

```
Name:     hello
Version:  0.0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason why no one suggested using lookahead and lookbehind? I got here trying to do the exact same thing and `(?<=<title>).+(?=<\/title>)` works great. It will only match whats between parentheses so you don't have to do the whole group thing.