# Is whitespace allowed within XML/HTML tags?

Tags: html, xml, syntax, tags, whitespace

I know how white space is handled in text nodes for XML and HTML, but I'm uncertain about white spaces inside tag elements themselves.  Obviously, white spaces are used inside tags to separate attributes, but is it valid to have white spaces after '<' or before '>'?

For example:

```
<  foo  >
< /foo >
```

Or even:

```
<foo>
< /  foo >
```

Are these tags valid XML?  What about HTML, assuming they were actual HTML tag names?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The [specification (section 3.1 Start-tags, end-tags, and empty-element tags)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) says that there is no white space between the `'<'` and the tag name, between `'</'` and the tag name, or inside `'/>'`. You can add white space after the tag name, though:

```
<foo            >
</foo        >
<bar
/>
```

Comment: is it valid then to break up long HTML tags into separate lines? For example: `<a heref="/something/" (newline, indent) title="something"> (newline) </a>` -- for example, in the case of long tags containing PHP code inside, to make it more readable.

Comment: @fakaff: Yes, that is valid. Line breaks, tabs and spaces are all white space characters, and you can have as much white space as you like after the tag name and between attributes (and even around the `=` in an attribute).

Answer (score 8):

`</` and `/>` are tokens, so whitespace between the two characters would be a syntax error. And as [Guffa pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314535/white-space-inside-xml-html-tags/3314572#3314572), whitespace isn't allowed between the opening token and the name. But you're fine adding whitespace between the element tag and the closing `>`(or `/>`) token.

**EDIT** to reflect Guffa's correct citing of the XML specification.

Answer (score 6):

The HTML[5] standard appears to agree exactly with the XML standard, as described by Guffa...

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags

Answer (score 0):

You can't start with a space, but you can (optionally) end with one (before the second angle bracket, that closes the first tag).

Comment: This answer adds nothing to the existing ones.

Comment: @Pyves neither does your comment ;)