# Extract title from HTML content

Tags: regex

Given the following HTML content (limited to the absolute *minimum* I require):

[image]

How would I be able to extract `Page Title` using Regex?

Comment: Are you only grabbing titles or are you going to be parsing out more from the document? If so, use an HTML parser.

Comment: You may look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/148481) answer

Comment: Wow :O Happened to have missed that. So should I use an HTML parser, and if so, which one?

Comment: It depends on what language you want to use. The main reason for an HTML parser is the malformed nature of HTML/XML.

Comment: The language is C# (if that's what you mean). I still feel that an HTML parser is overkill in my situation. What if we assume that the pattern is always exactly this way, can't I better use regex?

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, regular expressions may not be suitable for a bullet-proof method. E.g. using regex, it would be difficult to check if the `<title>` tag were part of a quoted string within the HTML. That's a recurring response on StackOverflow for questions like this. But personally, I think you've got a point that a parser would be overkill for such a simple extraction. If you're looking for a method that works *most* of the time, one of the following should surfice.

**Option 1: Lookbehind / lookahead**

```
(?<=<title[\s\n]*>[\s\n]*)(.(?![\s\n]*</title[\s\n]*>))*
```

This uses [lookbehind and lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for the tags - .NET has a sophisticated regex engine that allows for infinite repetition so you can even check for whitespace/return characters between the tag name and end brace (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314535/white-space-inside-xml-html-tags#3314572)).

**Option 2: Capturing group**

```
<title[\s\n]*>[\s\n]*(.*)[\s\n]*</title[\s\n]*>
```

Similar but slightly simpler - the whole regex match includes the start and end tags. The first (and only) capturing group `(.*)` captures the bit that is of interest in between.

Visualisation:
[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/nTVcC3ltpInvzX3W)