# Alternatives to Python's re.search

Tags: python, regex

I am using re.search to check if a string to text is found in a html page. Sometimes it does not find the string although it is definitely there. For example I would like to find: `<div class="dlInfo-Speed">` Does anyone know how to create regex to find that string?

Does anyone know of any good alternatives to re.search?

Thanks

Comment: "Sometimes it does not find the string although it is definitely there" - switching to BeautifulSoup or whatever may not solve this problem. You may want to take a closer look at that HTML first and figure out why you're not finding the text with your regex.

Comment: Do you have an example ? I don't think you can't find something with regex.

Comment: However using regexp for parsing XML-like stuff could easily become painful.

Comment: I think the problem is I am not creating proper regex strings for my searches. for example I would like to find: <div class="dlInfo-Speed">   Does anyone know how to create regex to find that string?

Comment: Show us the search expression you are using. In principle you do not need something as powerful as Regex for a simple string match. A properly formed Regex should always find a match if it exists. As was pointed out, _parsing_ HTML is best done with BeautifulSoup - but that is not what you say you are trying to do...

Comment: Could it be that there are additional white spaces etc. in the string you are searching for? In that case, you might want to replace spaces in your search string with "any number of white space". If you could show an example of a line that DIDNT match and the expression you are using to find it, you will get an answer very quickly.

Comment: If you MUST troubleshoot your regex, a tool like http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ is extremely useful

Comment: http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php?title=1171:_Perl_Problems

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to determine if a substring is present, you can use *in* for that.

```
 if some_substring in some_string:
      do_something_exciting()
```

Comment: Good post! Not to mention keyword "in" is around 8 times faster than re.search for me -- who would have thought?

Answer (score 2):

As for a regex, this is the best I got right now:

```
if re.search(r"<[dD][iI][vV]\s+.*?class="dlInfo-Speed".*?>(.*?)</[dD][iI][vV]>",
             html_doc,
             re.DOTALL):
    print "found"
else:
    print "not found"
```

http://regexr.com?37iqr

---

I found that regex's are usually not the best solution for %99 of problems like this.

My alternative is BeautifulSoup: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Here's how to solve it with bs4:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)
tag = soup.find("div", class_="dlInfo-Speed")

print tag.string #one way to get the contents
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted, it is possible that the string is not found because other HTML is mixed in with it. It's also possible that it's formatted in such a way that there are newlines in between the tag attributes, like:

```
some text goes here <div
class="dlInfo-Speed"> More text
```

or even

```
some text goes here <div class="dlInfo-Speed"
> More text
```

You can write a regex that will account for whitespace (including newlines and tabs) in all the places it may occur:

```
re.search(text, r'<div \s+ class="dlInfo-Speed" \s* >', re.VERBOSE)
```

But overall I strongly agree with the comment that for anything more than very simple, well-defined searches, it is usually best to parse the HTML properly and walk the document tree to find what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually, [whitespace is not permitted between the opening bracket and the tag name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3314572/20670).

Comment: @Floris: He's using `re.VERBOSE` to make the regex easier to read.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks, and apparently according to the spec it may not appear around the `=` of an attribute setting either. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance that the string that fails to be found is mixed with some html tags:

```
<div>string you are <span class="x">looking</span> for</div>
```

Maybe you should try removing html tags (unless they contain the string you search for) so the text is easier to search through. A simple way to do it using regex:

```
text = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', html_page)
if some_substring in text:
    do_something(text)
```

As for re.search alternatives, you can use string *index* method.

```
try:
    index = html_data.index(some_substring)
    do_something(html_data)
except ValueError:
    # string not found
    pass
```

or even *find* method:

```
if html_data.find(some_substring) >= 0:
    do_something(html_data)
```