# href="" link not working

Tags: html, href, location-href

Only one of my links on my navigation pane on my website is not working, the "About Me" link. When I click on it, the page turns white.
When I click on the other two, they go to the correct page. I cannot figure out what is wrong. Anyone have a clue?

Here is my code:

```
<td> 
[Home] <a href= "aboutme.html"> [About Me] </a> 
<a href= "reflection.html"> [Reflection]</a> <a href="vitae.html"> [Vitae] </a>
</td>
```

Comment: maybe the aboutme.html is empty, check/debug the aboutme,html  html code.

Comment: Since the page turns white, that means that the file is there but its empty. You need to add some html code in order to see something.

Comment: either that, or there are some unclosed tags which may be causing this problem

Answer (score 0):

When I copy and pasted your code into my editor your tags have spaces in them. I don't think that will work. Also are all of your html files in the same file?

Comment: This is only a comments worth, not really valid for an answer.

Comment: Yes, it is not part of the specifications: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314535/white-space-inside-xml-html-tags

Answer (score -1):

Your code has unnecessary spaces in it, try the following:

```
<table>
    <td>[Home]
        <a href="aboutme.html">[About Me]</a> 
        <a href="reflection.html">[Reflection]</a>
        <a href="vitae.html">[Vitae]</a>
    </td>
</table>
```

Please note that you seem to be missing the Home link.

If your issue navigating to aboutme.html persists, you may need to check that your path is correct, and that you are indeed hosting it in the correct location. Does this "white page" display any text etc?

Comment: Spaces will not affect this