# Will extra space in tag syntax cause errors? (will something like <tr > cause problems)

Tags: html, tags, dreamweaver

I'm noticing that Dreamweaver isn't flagging syntax that accidentally includes extra spaces, like a table row that's:

```
<tr >
```

Will there potentially be errors as a result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [White space inside XML/HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314535/white-space-inside-xml-html-tags)

Answer (score 1):

This is permitted per the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags) and shouldn't cause errors in any compliant browser:

> After the attributes, or after the tag name if there are no attributes, there may be one or more space characters.