# Why is jQuery function not working in IE11 browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-11

I have this function working on every browser except IE 11.

```
$(".someClass p").each(function() {
  if(/Trident.*rv:/.test(navigator.userAgent))
   $(this).replaceWith('<h3>' + this.innerHTML + '</h3>');
});
```

This shows the below error on the console:

> SCRIPT1014 Invalid Character

Comment: It doesn't say where this character lives?

Comment: Why would you built invalid markup (`< h3 >`, `< /h3 >`)? O.o

Comment: I don't see any IE11 specific error stuff.  Though I do see a use case for `wrap()`

Comment: I tested your code in IE11 and it appears to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/3vx0qtdu/1/. Are you certain it's this code block causing the error?

Comment: Re: Andreas' comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3314572/1264804

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan When I run this code in the console it works fine, but in my code works on every browser except IE 11

Comment: _"but in my code works on every browser"_ - `< h3 >Foo< /h3 >` is the expected output ([test](https://jsbin.com/begudiruge/1/edit?html,js,output))? O.o

Comment: @Andreas that was just for stack overflow purposes, already fixed it, but that's not my main issue here

Comment: I made a test with this code. https://textuploader.com/15nhb! This is the output I got in IE 11. https://i.postimg.cc/SxKZdSLy/126.png I find that code is working fine and there is no any error. can you please try to make a test with this code and check whether it is working or not? Let us know about your testing result, We will try to provide further suggestions. If needed.

Comment: thanks for response @Deepak-MSFT, yes the code works fine when I test in the IE console also, but once I add it to my script.js it works fine in every browser but not in IE

Comment: @Diego, Can you post your sample script file which can produce the issue? We will try to make a test with it to check for the issue. Thanks for your understanding.