# Will extra space *within* an HTML tag break certain browsers?

Tags: html

When mixing HTML and PHP in a document, I sometimes come to a situation where it may be desirable from a purely programming standpoint to insert an extra space *within* an HTML tag. If there is an extra space, will this affect some browsers? It seems to work fine on the popular browsers I have tested.

**Example:**

```
    <li <?php if ($ActiveItem == "tasklist") { echo "class=active"; } ?>>Task List</li>
```

would render

```
    <li >Task List</li>
```

if `$ActiveItem` does not equal `"tasklist"`

**vs.**

```
    <li<?php if ($ActiveItem == "tasklist") { echo " class=active"; } ?>>Task List</li>
```

which would render

```
    <li>Task List</li>
```

I know it is preferable to use version 2, but when editing the source code, the editors I use can't detect where the `<li>` begins, making it harder to debug code if there is a syntax error.

So, the question is, will `<li >` (and other elements with extra spaces *within* the tag) render correctly in browsers?

Comment: Nope, it won't do anything.

Comment: no, it will not break any browser having an extra space.

Comment: I can't say for certain on all browsers, but it's not a problem assuming they follow the spec. See [this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314535/white-space-inside-xml-html-tags).

Comment: Side note that the HTML parser is a very different beast from XML and the largely gone days of XHTML, but the above linked answer is still true anyway as the spacing in the tags is defined the same way.

Comment: I actually searched for the answer here and that 9-year-old answer did not come up for some reason.

Comment: No problem @ScottM.Stolz it happens - happy phping :)

Comment: According to the [HTML standard, section 12.1.2.1](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#start-tags), you can have as many whitespaces as you want.

Comment: By the way, thanks everyone.