# python, how to add variable value from xml response?

Tags: xml, python-2.7

I am getting an xml response containing data from a web site. I want to pick out the data within specific xml tags `<dcdIntegerValue>531</dcdIntegerValue>` and assign it to a variable. Currently I'm using "response_body" to get said response output. I am using python 2.7 and httplib if that matters. I'm not sure where to find information on how to do this. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks
Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't use a regex ?

```
import re
import urllib
stream=urllib.urlopen("http://....")
result=re.search('<dcdIntegerValue>(\d*)</dcdIntegerValue>',stream.read(),re.IGNORECASE)
if result:
     value=result.group(1)
```

Maybe a little "brutal" but i think it works.

Inspired by :
[extract contents of regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327369/extract-contents-of-regex)

Answer (score 4):

You either can use pythons ElementTree:

edit:
i forgot every item in this list is a type of element. You should get the contents by instead using:

```
number = int(item.text)
```

---

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

xmltree = et.ElementTree(file="yourxmlfile.xml")
intList = xmltree.getroot().iterfind(".//dcdIntegerValue")

for item in intList:
    number =int(item.text)
    #do whatever you want with your number
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know why I would be getting the error "TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Element'

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for your edit. That worked for me as well. Already marked the other one as the answer so I'll give your's a +1. Thanks!!!