# How to determine if an optional word exists or not

Tags: python, regex

I am using regex to process some files, for example if I have the following lines, and I need to capture the Example number, and whether there is an ERROR or not.

```
Example 1: bla bla bla
Example 2: bla bla ERROR
Example 3: bla bla
```

I'm doing `'Example\s+(\d+):.*(?:ERROR)?'`, it gives me the Example number, but how can I know if `ERROR` exists?

---

Update:

I change non-capture group to capture group, but it still doesn't work.

```
In [77]: line = 'Example 5: abv ERROR zyx'

In [78]: re.search('Example\s+(\d+).+(ERROR)?', line).group(2)

In [79]: re.search('Example\s+(\d+).+(ERROR)', line).group(2)
Out[79]: 'ERROR'
```

I am totally confused, the word is there but why the optional capture group is not capturing it?

Comment: Is `ERROR` always at the end of the string?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: Well since you didn't reply right away, I wrote an answer with both options available :)

Comment: I wonder why the answers are downvoted that heavily here. I think the question is not clear. LWZ, please add expected output. Do you want the numbers only, or do you want to get tuples: `('NUMBER', 'ERROR')`, `('NUMBER', '')`? If you only want number after `Example` on a line where `ERROR` follows, use [`Example\s+(\d+):(?=.*ERROR)`](https://regex101.com/r/BVNBAv/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ERROR` is always at the end of the line, you can do the following:

- Convert the non-capturing group `(?:ERROR)` to a capturing group.
- Replace your greedy match for `.*` with a lazy match `.*?`.
- Add the end of line assertion `$` at the end.

So, your regex would look something like this:

```
Example\s+(\d+):.*?(ERROR)?$
```

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/OcShFj/1).

Then, you can check whether the second group is empty or not.

---

If `Error` doesn't have to be at the end of the line, you can adjust the above regex to look something like this:

```
Example\s+(\d+):(?:.*?(ERROR)|.*)
```

This part `(?:.*?(ERROR)|.*)` of the regex works like this:

```
(?:       # This is the start of a non-capturing group.
.*?       # Lazy match for zero or more characters (same as the above solution).
(ERROR)   # Matches the characters `ERROR` literally, placed in a capturing group to be able to check if empty (same as the above solution).
|         # Alternative. Meaning match either what's before the `|` or what's after it _inside the non-capturing group_.
.*        # Greedy match for zero or more characters (same as you first original regex).
```

So, this basically looks for any number of characters (lazy) followed by `ERROR` **Or** any number of characters (greedy) *not followed by `ERROR`*.

[Here's a demo](https://regex101.com/r/LLmR0e/1).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I guess my question is how do I check whether the second group is empty or not?

Comment: Well, I don't really know python. I was just answering the regex question :D. Anyhow, with a quick search, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1327389/4934172) which explains how to access the group. And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9573244/4934172) about how to check if the string is empty.

Comment: Oh! I got it! A capturing group can be empty but still exists. I made a non-capturing group so the 2nd group doesn't exist at all. Thanks!

Comment: @LWZ yes, the capturing group can be empty. You only use a non-capturing group if you don't care about what is captured by it, but you need to use a group to complete the regex (for example, in order to use "or" `|` like what I did in my second regex). Please let me know if there's anything else not clear.

Comment: It's still not working after I use the capturing group, please see the updated question.

Comment: @LWZ Based on your edit, it looks like you didn't use any of the two regex patterns I suggested! Since you said `ERROR` doesn't have to be at the end, please use the second regex in my answer and let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171108/discussion-between-lwz-and-ahmed-abdelhameed).

Answer (score -1):

What you want to do? Your current solutions should work with a bit modification:

`re.findall(r'^Example\s+(\d+):|(ERROR)', line)`

If returning array length is 2 then it means ERROR is found.

Example if ERROR exists:

```
>>> line = 'Example 5: abv ERROR zyx'
>>> re.findall(r'^Example\s+(\d+):|(ERROR)', line)
[('5', ''), ('', 'ERROR')]
```

Example if ERROR does not exist:

```
>>> line = 'Example 5: abv zyx'
>>> re.findall(r'^Example\s+(\d+):|(ERROR)', line)
[('5', '')]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the answer. It seems like you just copy and pasted the posters question. Perhaps an example in python showing the behavior you are talking about would be helpful.