# python regular expression: how to extract 'A =BC= D' -> 'BC'

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm at a loss because I don't know how to write regular expressions of python to extract particular strings such as `A =BC= D =EF=` -> `'BC', 'EF`. I searched a lot but couldn't write this operation. please help.

Comment: This isn't very well defined.  Could you be more clear bout exactly what you are looking for this regex to do?

Comment: thansk for helpful answers! please ask one more question! how about extracting strings from only left-side equal mark not just both side such as `A =BC= D =EF= =G H` -> `'BC', 'EF', 'G'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
=..=
```

[regex.101](https://regex101.com/r/h5T2Ak/2)

result:

> Match 1
>
> Full match 2-6 `=BC=`
>
> Match 2
>
> Full match 9-13    `=EF=`

Here is a nice tutorial:
[Regex tutorial — A quick cheatsheet by examples](https://medium.com/factory-mind/regex-tutorial-a-simple-cheatsheet-by-examples-649dc1c3f285)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `=([^=]+)=` to extract character (except `=`) any (non-zero) number of times. You can extract the contents within the equal signs using [groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327369/extract-part-of-a-regex-match#1327389).

If you want to match exactly two characters within equal signs, `=([^=]{2})=` should do.

Comment: thanks a lot! very helpful answer! please ask one more question. How about only left-side equal `A =BC= D =EF= =G  H` -> `'BC', 'EF', 'G'` ?

Comment: @user3620568 Ideally you should edit your question to include this follow-up or ask a separate question, but try `=([^=]+)(?:=| )`. The only issue with that is that it includes the space after `G` in the capture. So you'll get `'BC', 'EF', 'G '`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i will be careful next time.

Comment: @user3620568 If this answers your question adequately, please mark as accepted. No problem!

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to use the Regex library

```
import re
```

Then you can use re.findall(pattern, string) to get a list of all the substrings that match your pattern.

It's not clear from your question what defines the 'particular strings' you are looking for. Assuming you are looking for everything between two equals signs, but not greedily (not including equals signs inside), you could use the regex `"=(.*?)="`.

```
import re
m = re.findall("=(.*?)=", "A =BC= D =EF=")
```

Result:

> >>>m
>
> ['BC', 'EF']