# This regex to match a word surrounded by {} does not work

Tags: regex

So here's my regex to match a word after "define" or "define:"

```
((?<=define |define: )\w+)
```

That part works well and all. But when I add the part where it also should match word between {} if it can, it matches everything.

```
((?<=define |define: )\w+)|([^{][A-Z]+[^}])
```

[The regex with the examples](https://regexr.com/4g88i)

The thing that I noticed is that when I add ^ at first [{] then it ruins everything and I don't understand why.

Comment: So is your question "Why does adding `^` ruin everything?" or "How do I match everything in `{}`?"

Comment: @Sweeper I would prefer both if you can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does using `[^{]` not work?

By using `[^{]`, your regex becomes:

```
[^{][A-Z]+[^}]
```

In words, this translates to:

- character that's not a `{`
- a bunch of letters
- character that's not a `}`

Note how nothing in your regex enforces the idea that the "a bunch of letters" part has to be between `{}`s. It just says that it has to be after a character that is not `{`, and before a character that is not `}`. By this logic, even something like `ABC` would match because `A` is not `{`, `B` is the bunch of letters, and `C` is not `}`.

> How to match a word between `{}`?

You can use this regex:

```
{([A-Z]+)}
```

And get group 1.

I don't think that you should combine this with the regex that matches a word after `define`. You should use 2 separate regexes because these are two completely different things.

So split it into two regexes:

```
(?<=define |define: )\w+
```

and

```
{([A-Z]+)}
```

Comment: But that regex matches {} too. Sure I can do replace, but is there any way to just make it match stuff between {} and not {} too?

Comment: @Boypro You _could_ use `(?<={)[A-Z]+(?=})` but that's a lot slower, so my recommendation is to just use the regex in the answer, and just get group 1 from it instead. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327369/extract-part-of-a-regex-match) if you don't know how.

Comment: Cool. Thank you!

Comment: @Boy pro, if you use PCRE engine, you can match only what is between `{}` without using any group constructs with the following regex `{\K[^}]+`. See a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/XsKuDb/2).

Comment: @Junitar In a previous revision of the question, it's tagged python, so I assumed OP is using python.

Comment: @Sweeper Yeah I use Python

Answer (score 2):

You are using negated character classes the way we would use positive lookbehind `(?<=)` and positive lookahead `(?=)`. They are fundamentally different and, as opposed to lookbehind or lookahead, character classes consume characters.

Hence:

- `[^{][A-Z]` matches a capital letter that is preceded by a character other than `{`.
- `[A-Z][^}]` matches a capital letter that is followed by a character other than `}`.

So if you try to match the letters in `{OO}` with the regex `[^{][A-Z]+[^}]`, it is totally normal that your regex won't match anything because you have two letters, one preceded by a `{`, the other followed by a `}`.