# How do I extract the span and match from a regex search?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have the following data:

```
some_string = """
Dave Martin
615-555-7164
173 Main St., Springfield RI 559241122
davemartin101@exampledomain.com

Charles Harris
800-555-5669
969 High St., Atlantis VA 340750509
charlesharris101@exampledomain.com
"""
```

I used the following to find a pattern:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\d\d\d(-|\.)\d\d\d(-|\.)\d\d\d\d')
matches = pattern.finditer(some_string)
```

Printing the `re` object shows:

```
for match in matches:
    print(match)

<re.Match object; span=(21, 33), match='615-555-7164'>
<re.Match object; span=(131, 143), match='800-555-5669'>
```

I want to extract the span and match fields. I found this link [Extract part of a regex match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327369/extract-part-of-a-regex-match) that shows how to use `group()`:

```
nums = []
for match in matches:
    nums.append(match.group(0))
```

I get the following result:

```
print(nums)
['615-555-7164', '800-555-5669']
```

Similar to the other StackOverlow thread above, how can I extract the span?

This thread was marked for deletion by someone and then it was deleted. The justification for deletion was that I was seeking advice on software... which I was not. https://i.imgur.com/sbCfekf.png

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract/do here?  You never actually mentioned this.

Comment: Hello @IamWarmducher, may I ask if what you mean by the `span`? You mean `span` tags?

Comment: This is fully spelled out in the docs. Please read them before posting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking for the tuple storing the begin and end index of the matches, just use `span`. Note that the parameter for `span` works the same way as `group` as they both take the match group index, and index `0` stores the entire match (while in your case index `1` and `2` match `(-|\.)`).

```
for match in matches:
    print(match.span(0))
```

Output:

```
(13, 25)
(103, 115)
```

And for extracting the match fields, yes, your approach works just fine. It will be better if you extract both the match fields and span in the same loop.

```
nums = []
spans = []
for match in matches:
    nums.append(match.group(0))
    spans.append(match.span(0))
```

Besides, please be aware that `finditer` gives you an `Iterator`, which means that once it reaches the end of the iterable, it's done. You will need to create a new one if you want to iterate it through again.