# How to extract (c)hunk headers only from diff?

Tags: python, git, git-diff

The results of diff will give you :

```
    @@ -74,6 +73,7 @@ 
    <dependency> <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId> 
    <artifactId>bonecp-test
    - commons</artifactId> 
    + <classifier>${project.classifier}</classifier>     
    <scope>test</scope>
```

I want to way to get only these numbers from the headers   74,6 and 73,7
; any idea how can I achieve that? I am using python code

Comment: Have you tried regex?

Comment: well , I do not have experience at all in regex

Comment: you don't even need regexps: print lines that start with "@@"

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? This line starts with `@@` so you can get line-by-line and check `line.startswith("@@")`, and later you can `data = line.split(" ")` to create list with `["@@", "-74,6", "+73,7", "@@"]` and get `data[1]` `data[2]`

Comment: What is the the goal behind this? Also: Are the amount of context lines relevant to you? Would having no context lines (`-U0`) be an option? I'm asking this because the number of context lines will affect what numbers are in the `@@` lines. So yeah... that's why I wonder what you need this for. (And your fake/invalid diff hunk example isn't helping :D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use regex to extract what you want

```
([-\+]?\d+,[-\+]?\d+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/1DPH5e/2

If you want to make it more specific in case your diff includes similar patterns:

```
@@\s([-\+]?\d+,[-\+]?\d+)\s([-\+]?\d+,[-\+]?\d+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/3G42Lz/2

You can then extract the groups from python. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1327389/3730626) has a good description of how to do that.

Comment: how about if I need -74 to appear in the group(1)

Comment: You move the bracket forward. Updated the answer.